# Bind Click Event to GMap Markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, mouseclick-event

I want to bind a Clickevent to Markers of a GMap, which are already there when the page is loaded. So I dont want to create new Markers, i only want to bind a Click Event to existing Markers.

The Map and the Markers are already placed and now i want to do some jQuery Stuff when the user is clicking on a Marker of the map.

I only have found solutions how to create new Markers and so on. Im working with the API v3.

Comment: You need a reference to the markers. When you say they are already there, where do they come from? Please show some code.

Comment: Its in a Drupal CMS. The editor can specify a Position in the Backend of the cms. This position is shown as a marker on a google map. So there is a GMap with a lot of Markers. You know what i mean?

Comment: Yes, but these markers also will also be created somehow by a clientside script, this part would be important to see how to access the markers. Can you give a link to the site?

Comment: No my Site isnt online yet. but this seems to be something similar: http://www.climbnyc.com/climb

Comment: I have a KML that provides me with the markers.Then how do i do it?